# how to active first menu default without using hover

Tags: magento-1.8

I m using [this extension](https://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/magento-mega-menu-extension) mega menu in magento 1

When i click a parent menu how default show a 1st child and 1st sub child

css:

```
.nocustom ul{
   opacity: 1 !important;
   visibility: visible !important;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   left: 120%;
   top: 30px;
}
```

script

```
jQuery('.parentMenu').mouseover(function() {  

 jQuery('.subcate:first-child').addClass('nocustom');

});
```

output

[image]

I excepted like [this menu](https://www.eurocarparts.com/car-parts)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/v98vLrgq/ try this

Comment: i will try and update u @Prathap

Comment: you are modify `women` <li>?

Comment: i cant get you @rakesh

Comment: you can find of <li> then add condition

Comment: i   added a script file for first menu active default  its done but i can go for second one first one not close

Comment: you want to all time parent category menu active?

Comment: no  i need when i  move to next one, prev one is close  but it not happen

Comment: when i click parent  1st child shows default without using hover and next i click a 2nd child  shows 2nd sub child closes a 1st child

Comment: i want like  this car parts menu (https://www.eurocarparts.com/car-parts) @rakesh